# How to check if an UltraTree node already exists

Tags: vb.net, ultratree

I need to loop through data and add nodes to an UltraTree object for each facility.  But it fails when there are multiple records for a given facility.

**System.ArgumentException:** 'Key already exists, key: ts1'

So I'm trying to check the existing nodes and only add if it isn't already there.

```
'facNode is an UltraTreeNode
'nodeName is a string

If (facNode.Nodes.Contains(nodeName) = False) Then
    Dim selectable = facNode.Nodes.Add(nodeName, "Study Director " & studyFacility.SMStudyDirectorName)

    [Do Stuff]
End If
```

Unfortunately, ***facNode.Nodes.Contains(nodeName)*** always evaluates to false. Visual Studio says, "The expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated."

I've found many threads/articles that say each key must be unique, but I have not been able to find the proper syntax to check if a key already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It's the Exists() method instead of Contains().

`If (facNode.Nodes.Exists(nodeName) = False) Then`